# Stack Level Too Deep in Production Rails App - How to Get Details?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, deployment, logging

I am getting up and running with Spree in production on a 256MB Slicehost slice with MySQL, Mongrel, and Nginx.  I am getting this error every time I try to access any URL in the app:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  compass (0.8.17) lib/compass/app_integration/rails/action_controller.rb:7:in `process'
  vendor/plugins/haml/rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:44:in `call'
```

(Some more test url requests are in this [pastie](http://pastie.org/806646))

What are the advanced (but free and open source) debugging strategies/tools I should use while in production mode so I can do better at solving this problem?

It's slightly different each time depending on the controller.  I have tried [increasing my stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242617/how-to-increase-stack-size-for-a-ruby-app-recursive-app-getting-stack-level-too), but that doesn't help because there's probably just some loop I can't find.

The question is, how do I get a more detailed report of the exact output while in production?

I am using [Deprec](http://deprec.failmode.com/) and Capistrano to execute all server side commands.  I am running a mongrel cluster of 3.  The log files I see are:

```
current/log$ ls
development.log
testsite.com-error.log
mongrel.8000.log
mongrel.8001.log
mongrel.8002.log
mongrel.log
production.log
testsite.com-access.log
```

I'm just looking for some advanced debugging strategies/tools while in production mode so I can do better at solving this problem.  Maybe some cap tasks for streaming/debugging (or conditionally break-pointing!) the production app (really, a staging app) locally (do people do that?), or something that spits out every single thing that executes in code?

Thanks

Comment: Have you yet checked production.log? That's where I'd first expect errors in production to be... though I'm not necessarily sure it would give you any more data.

Comment: yeah that first snippet is from production.log, and I have temporarily set "config.log_level = :debug" in production mode, but they don't give me too much info :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check all of your gems and plugins and any other dependencies your application might have: I'd guess that you're missing something (or have the wrong version of something) and it's failing badly enough that it can't even spit out a can't find require message.

Answer (score 0):

check your action controller. On line 7 is most likely where the loop occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have initiated some endless recursion on line 7 of your controller. Check if you are  calling the same method inside the method.